# Don't understand the typing of Scala's delimited continuations (A @cpsParam[B,C])

Tags: scala, functional-programming, types, scala-2.8, continuations

I'm struggling to understand what precisely does it mean when a value has type `A @cpsParam[B,C]` and what types of this form should I assign to my values when using the delimited continuations facility.

I've looked at some sources:

http://lamp.epfl.ch/~rompf/continuations-icfp09.pdf

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096

http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/07/delimited-continuations-explained-in.html

http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/02/delimited-continuations-in-scala_24.html

but they didn't give me much intuition into this. In the last link, the author tries to give an explicit explanation, but it is not clear enough anyway.

> The A here represents the output of the computation, which is also the input to its continuation. The B represents the return type of that continuation, and the C represents its "final" return type—because shift can do further processing to the returned value and change its type.

I don't understand the difference between "output of the computation", "return type of the continuation" and "final return type of the continuation". They sound like synonyms.

Comment: I'm always sad when folks don't get to see my blog post: http://suereth.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-you-should-think-about-delimited.html 

I cover this in detail, as it was something that frustrated me greatly looking at existing sources on the internet.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I shall look at your post.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, people helped me with this one elsewhere. Here is the answer:

```
reset ({
    ...
    ...shift((k:A=>B) => ...::C)::A...
    ...
}::B)::C
```

So, `shift` is a hole of type `A` in a computation `{...}` of type `B`. The argument of `shift` returns a value of type `C` and that's why `reset ({...})` has type `C`.

The key trick in understanding this stuff was to see that `{...}` and `reset {...}` have different type depending on what type the `shift`'s argument returns.

For example:

```
reset ({
    "number "+shift((k:Int=>String) => List(k(1), k(2), k(3)))
})
```

returns `List("number 1", "number 2", "number 3")`.

Here `A` is `Int`, `B` is `String`, `C` is `List[String]` because `{"number" + _}` is (here) a function from `Int` to `String` and the argument of `shift`, given that function, produces a `List[String]`, which becomes result of the `reset({...})`.

Answer (score 1):

I am still in a process of figuring out the exact typing rules/implications involved in here.

It seems easy/easier if the types in the examples are "simple enough" to "fit well" as shown above, but it becomes more interresting/difficult (at least for me) in comparing things to the typing give by tiark rompf:

```
|- e: A@cpsParam[B,C]; {[|r|]}: U
-----------------------------------------------------
[|val x: A = e; r|] = [|e|].map( (x: A) => {[|r|]} )
```

so the result of `[|e|].map( (x: A) => {[|r|]} )` will have the type `Shift[U,B,C]` according to the definition of map given in tiark's paper.

Here U is not necessarily be the same as B.

So far I do not understand why U is allowed to be different from B without something like
`U <: B` given in the definition of map in tiark's paper.

What am I missing repsectively failing to understand here?

Any tips/ideas?